# Data filter without showing all items by default

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to know how to build a data filter that doesn't show items unless u choose one of the categories almost all codes over the internet came standard so if u have 100 items there gonna be shown by default I want one without showing all automatically unless I decided to show it all please if someone have a link for a tutorial please send or send the code thanks.

Comment: We don't provide codes here. Start coding and if you have questions ask here.

Comment: please check this code pen when i do refresh all items shows again :/  https://codepen.io/bastilimbach/pen/kefBI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will solve the issue you just need to put an if condition to check whether there is value or not

```js
let list = ["India", "Us", "Iran", "Irak", "Israel"];

function filterData(e) {
  let result;

  if (e.value.length > 0) {
    result = list
      .filter((t) => t.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.value) > -1)
      .sort(
        (a, b) =>
          a.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterTermValue) -
          b.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.filterTermValue)
      );
  } else {
    result = [];
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" onkeydown="filterData(this)" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular [ForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) combined with the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function should do the trick. Instead of just giving you the basic code, try coding it up yourself to get a better understanding of how it works.